# How do you create factories for classes with dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, factory

If I have a class that requires a dependency through its constructor:

```
public MyClass( IDependencyInterface dependency )
```

and the dependency uses a factory/builder (it is still confusing to me the distinction between the two) to set its parameters:

```
IDependencyInterface dependency = dependencyFactory
                                       .ChangeSomeParameter(someValue)
                                       .ChangeSomeOtherParameter(someOtherValue)
                                       .Build();
```

How do I create the factory for MyClass without passing in other factories to instantiate the required dependancies?

```
public MyClassFactory
{
    private SomeParam _someParam;
    private IDependencyFactory _dependencyFactory;

    public myClassFactory( IDependencyFactory dependencyFactory)
    {
        _dependencyFactory = dependencyFactory;
    }

    public ImyClassFactory ChangeSomeParameter(someParam)
    {
        _someParam = someParam;
    }

    public IMyClass Build()
    {
        Dependency dependency = _dependencyFactory
                                   .ChangeSomeParameter( _SomeParam )
                                   .Build();
        return MyClass(dependency);
    }
}
```

How do I prevent from having to pass the factories of the dependencies required for me to build “MyClass” when I create my MyClassFactory? Or is it correct, that you need to pass in the factories of every dependency into the factory for the class with dependencies?

P.S. I plan on making the factories singletons that are instantiated at run time and passed around. Also I am new to Dependency Injection. Please let me know if there is a better way to use factories with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to dependency injection, I would say: **you don't**.

Resolving dependencies and creating the vast majority of factories is a purpose of the **dependency injection service provider**. You get this feature by using a dependency injection component *somebody else wrote*, e.g. [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/).

In general, application code merely lists its dependencies, for example by **merely declaring them** as constructor arguments. Services don't care how they or their dependencies are created. One role of dependency injection is *inversion of control* which popularly said means **don't call us, we'll call you**. This should especially hold for constructors when talking about dependency injection.

As soon as you start breaking your head over how to create or pass around factories, you're violating several principles of good design.

Have a look at the [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) article on learn.microsoft.com. It has more useful links at the bottom of the page. It is written with writing ASP.NET Core web sites/applications in mind, but most of the article in fact deals with the principles of modern software development (such as inversion of control) that apply in general for any application.